# json data is not fetching from url

Tags: android, json

I am making an android app to fetch the mailaddress which store in mysql data to check if mail address typed in edittext is unique or not but i always get null fron json url.      My json code is

```
    {"result":[{"mailId":"nikhilmanali@gmail.com"}]}
```

my android code is:

```
EditText et1,et2,et3,et4,et5;
    Button bu1;
    String mailCheck;
    String mail;
  //  TextView alert;
    String name,password,mailId,repass,number;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new AsyncTaskParse().execute();



        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,mailCheck,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
        et4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et4);
        et5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et5);
        name=et1.getText().toString();
        password=et2.getText().toString();
       /// alert=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.alert);4
        repass=et4.getText().toString();


            mailId=et3.getText().toString();
            number=et5.getText().toString();




        bu1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bu1);


        bu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {




            public void onClick(View v) {
                String t = et1.getText().toString();
                String t5 = et5.getText().toString();
                String one = et2.getText().toString();
                String two = et4.getText().toString();
                 mail = et3.getText().toString();




if(one.equals(two) ){

                    if (one.equals(two) && isEmailValid(mail,et3)) {


                            isInternetOn();



                    }
} else {
                        et4.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000'>Password not Match!</font>"));
                         focus(et4);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }








////////////////////////


    public class AsyncTaskParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

        // set your json string url here

        String yourJsonStringUrl = "http://www.example.com/checkMail.php?mailId="+mailId;

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}


        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // get json string from url

                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);


                if(json!=null) {
                    // get the array of users
                    dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("result");
                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(0);
                    //    na=c.getString("avg");

                    mailCheck = c.getString("mailId");

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: have you define internet permission in your manifest file?

Comment: check your json from following link if it is loading the json from url or not http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: @anjali sure i have define internet permission in my manifest file

Comment: yes when i am running this url the above data is loading

Comment: you have to call asynchronous after when you had value in edit text box not before inserting values and instead of hard coding parameters in url execute values while you are calling asynchronous.

Comment: srry i didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

Put your new `AsyncTaskParse().execute();` after   `mail = et3.getText().toString();`

Maybe you need to keep `AsyncTaskParse().execute();` inside your `onClick`